# R while loop help needed

Tags: r

So I've created a while loop to give a coordinate point, Xm and Ym, which follows a uniform distribution, where the point must be within a circle of radius 25. Below is the code for that:

```
outcome<-function()
{
done=0
while(done==0){
  Xm<-runif(1,-25,25)
  Ym<-runif(1,-25,25)
if (Xm^2+Ym^2<=25^2){
    z<-c(Xm,Ym)
    done=1
  }
 }
z
}
outcome()
```

I now need to do the same thing, 250 times. I've changed the code to this:

```
plotoutcome<-function()
{
  done=0
  while(done==0){
    Xm2<-runif(250,-25,25)
    Ym2<-runif(250,-25,25)
    if (Xm2^2+Ym2^2<=25^2){
      z<-c(Xm2,Ym2)
      done=1
    }
  }
  z
}
plotoutcome()
```

However when I run the second code, I get this error message: In if (Xm2^2 + Ym2^2 <= 25^2) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: what do you mean by " do the same thing, 250 times" ? You need all 250 to fulfill the condition?

Comment: The reason for the error is: in your ```outcome``` function you're creating a scalar via ```runif(1,...)``` while in ```plotoutcome``` you're creating a vector. as consequence, the condition in your ````if````-clause is vectorized.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to take advantage of `outcome`:

```
replicate(250, outcome())
```

But if a new function is needed, here is a `plotoutcome` function:

```
plotoutcome<-function()
{
  total <- 0
  done <- FALSE
  Xtmp <- numeric(250)
  Ytmp <- numeric(250)
  while(!done){
    Xm2 <- runif(1, -25, 25)
    Ym2 <- runif(1, -25, 25)
    i <- Xm2^2 + Ym2^2 <= 25^2
    if(i){
      total <- total + 1
      Xtmp[total] <- Xm2
      Ytmp[total] <- Ym2
    }
    done <- total == 250
  }
  list(X = Xtmp, Y = Ytmp)
}
do.call(cbind, plotoutcome())
```